Pass combination of brace-enclosed initializer lists and vectors to a variadic template
I want to write a table class which takes as argument multiple columns to create the table. This is my attempt to do so.
template <typename T = double>
class table
{
private:
    using type = std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<type>);
    using coltype = std::vector<type>;

    std::vector<coltype> m_data;

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    table(Args &&...args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) >= 2);
        static_assert((std::is_constructible_v<coltype, Args &&> && ...));
        (m_data.push_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    }
    ~table() = default;
    
    // ... other stuff
};

However, currently this doesn't work with brace-enclosed initializer lists. I intend to use it as follows:
std::vector<double> vec1{1.,2.,3.};
std::vector<double> vec2{4.,5.,6.};
table t1(vec1,vec2); //works
table t2({1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.}); //doesn't compile as brace-enclosed initializers doesn't have a type
table t3({1,2,3},vec1,vec2) // also possibly combinations

How can this be achieved? Is some implementation with std::initializer_list possible?

{..} has no type, and can only be deduced with std::initializer_list<T> or T(&)[N] (so not with Args&&....

Why not have directly explicit table(std::vector<coltype> v) : m_data(std::move(v)) {}? just "extra" {} at call site.

I tend to split things into dedicated classes. That way it's easier to write wrappers and c'tors for specific types. Here's a quick shot:
#include <vector>
template <typename T = double>
class Table {
public:
    class Cell {
    public:
        Cell(double d) : m_v(T(d)) {}
        Cell(int i) : m_v(T(i)) {}
        // ...

        T& getValue() { return m_v; }

    protected:
        T m_v;
    };

    class Row {
    public:
        Row(std::initializer_list<T> values) {
            for (auto v : values) {
                m_cells.emplace_back(v);
            }
        }

        T& operator[](size_t x) {
            return m_cells[x].getValue();
        }

    protected:
        std::vector<Cell> m_cells;
    };

    Table(std::initializer_list<Row> rows) {
        for (auto& row : rows) {
            m_rows.push_back(row);
        }
    }

    Row& operator[](size_t y) {
        return m_rows[y];
    }

protected:
    std::vector<Row> m_rows;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Table<> a({
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}
    });

    double cell = a[2][1];
    return 0;
}


Quick sketch for you to get started
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename type_t, std::size_t rows_v, std::size_t columns_v>
class Table
{
public:
    explicit Table(const type_t(&cells)[rows_v][columns_v])
    {
        for(std::size_t row{0ul}; row < rows_v; ++row)
        {
            for(std::size_t column{0ul}; column < columns_v; ++column)
            {
                m_cells[row][column] = cells[row][column];
            }
        }
    }

    auto& cells()
    {
        return m_cells;
    }

private:
    std::array<std::array<type_t, columns_v>, rows_v> m_cells;
};


int main()
{
    Table table{ {{1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.}} };
    for (const auto& row : table.cells())
    {
        for (const auto& cell : row)
        {
            std::cout << cell << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


You seem to want to use std::initializer list<T>.
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

template <typename T = double>
class table {
 private:
  using type = std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;
  static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<type>);
  using coltype = std::vector<type>;

  std::vector<coltype> m_data;

 public:
  table(std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>> args) { m_data = args; }
  ~table() = default;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<double> vec1{1., 2., 3.};
  std::vector<double> vec2{4., 5., 6.};
  table t1{vec1, vec2};  // works
  table t{{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}};
  table t3{{1, 2, 3}, vec1, vec2};  // also possibly combinations
}


Initializer lists are broken : C++Now 2018: Jason Turner “Initializer Lists Are Broken, Let's Fix Them”
